# Grouping Nodes from different nodes based on key

Tags: xml, xslt

** Group packing List by Invoice Number as Key into ASN Nodes**
    ----------------------------------------------------------
My Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SupplierInvoiceProcessing>
<Invoice>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>1</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>a1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details> 
<InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>a2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
</Invoice>
<Invoice>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>2</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>b1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>b2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<PackingList>
<IN>3</IN>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>c3</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
<PackingList>
<IN>1</IN>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>a1</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
</Invoice>
<Invoice>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>1</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>c1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>c2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
</Invoice>
<Invoice>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>2</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>d1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>d2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<PackingList>
<IN>4</IN>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>d4</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
<PackingList>
<IN>2</IN>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>b2</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
</Invoice>
</SupplierInvoiceProcessing>
```

XSLT 2.0 Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:ns0="urn:Shiseido.com:interface:SHISEIDOJAPAN" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns0:SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
<xsl:for-each-group select="ns0:SupplierInvoiceProcessing/Invoice" group-by="(Header/InvoiceNumber,IN)">
<AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
<ASN>
<Header>
<xsl:value-of select="Invoice/Header"/>
<InvoiceNumber><xsl:value-of select="Header/InvoiceNumber"/></InvoiceNumber>
<ETA><xsl:value-of select="Header/ETA"/></ETA>
<xsl:for-each-group select="//PackingList" group-by="concat(InvoiceNumber,IN)">
<PackingList>
<InvoiceNumber><xsl:value-of select="InvoiceNumber"/></InvoiceNumber>
<Cart><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/FOBTotalNoOfCartons"/></Cart>
</PackingList></xsl:for-each-group>
</Header>                   
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()/Details">
<Details>
<xsl:value-of select="Details"/>
<InvoiceNumber><xsl:value-of select="InvoiceNumber"/></InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber><xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber"/></OrderNumber>
</Details>
</xsl:for-each>                                                                 
</ASN>
</AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</ns0:SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
<AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
<ASN>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>1</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>a1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>a2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<PackingList>
<InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>a1</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
</ASN>
<ASN>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>2</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>b1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>b2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<PackingList>
<InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>b2</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
</ASN>
<ASN>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>1</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>c1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>c2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<PackingList>
<InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>c3</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
</ASN>
<ASN>
<Header>
<InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
<ETA>2</ETA>
</Header>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>d1</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<Details>
<InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
<OrderNumber>d2</OrderNumber>
</Details>
<PackingList>
<InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
<FOBTotalNoOfCartons>d4</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
</PackingList>
</ASN>
</AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
</SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
```

Comment: My expected result is 


ASN
H1
D1
D1
P1

ASN
H2
D2
D2
P2

ASN
H3
D3
D3
P3

ASN
H4
D4
D4
P4

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including an actual example of the XML input, your current XSLT and the expected output (as code, within the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you basically want to use the child elements of `Invoice`:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice/(Header, Details, PackingList)" group-by="InvoiceNumber, IN">
        <ASN>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </ASN>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGC that gives

```
<ASN>
   <Header>
         <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
         <ETA>1</ETA>
      </Header>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>a1</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>a2</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
   <PackingList>
         <IN>1</IN>
         <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>a1</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
      </PackingList>
</ASN>
<ASN>
   <Header>
         <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
         <ETA>2</ETA>
      </Header>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>b1</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>b2</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
   <PackingList>
         <IN>2</IN>
         <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>b2</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
      </PackingList>
</ASN>
<ASN>
   <PackingList>
         <IN>3</IN>
         <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>c3</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
      </PackingList>
   <Header>
         <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
         <ETA>1</ETA>
      </Header>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>c1</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>c2</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
</ASN>
<ASN>
   <Header>
         <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
         <ETA>2</ETA>
      </Header>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>d1</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
   <Details>
         <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
         <OrderNumber>d2</OrderNumber>
      </Details>
   <PackingList>
         <IN>4</IN>
         <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>d4</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
      </PackingList>
</ASN>
```

so if you add some wrapper elements like

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
        <AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice/(Header, Details, PackingList)" group-by="InvoiceNumber, IN">
                <ASN>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </ASN>
            </xsl:for-each-group>                
        </AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
    </SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
</xsl:template>
```

as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGC/1, then you get the desired result in terms of grouping the elements, I think you can then add

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
        <SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
            <AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice/(Header, Details, PackingList)" group-by="InvoiceNumber, IN">
                    <ASN>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[self::Header], current-group()[self::Details], current-group()[self::PackingList]"/>
                    </ASN>
                </xsl:for-each-group>                
            </AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
        </SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
    </xsl:template>
```

to get the right output order: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGC/2.

Comment: Thanks Martin Honnen, It worked as expected. Thanks again for prompt reply.

Comment: Hi Martin, If the Packing list invoice does not match header invoice, it generates tag like below:
<ASN>
<PL>
<IN>5</IN>
<Cartons>30</Cartons>
</PL>
<ASN>

If there is no header invoice matching packing list invoice number
I do not want that ASN tag..
Always want 
ASN
 Header
Details
PL

say my input is:
ASN
HeaderIN-1
DetailIn -1
PLIN-1

ASN
HeaderIN-2
DetailIN-2
PL-2

ASN
PL-3
ASN
PL-4

SO my output should be:
ASN
HeaderIN-1
DetailsIN-1
PLIN-1

ASN
HeaderIN-2
DetailsIN-2
PLIN-2

Comment: Does it work if as desired if you change `xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice/(Header, Details, PackingList)"` to `xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice[Header]/(Header, Details, PackingList)"`? If not, consider to ask a new question with the necessary details in a well-formatted way, it is hard to read code details in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Martin.
I posted as a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699181/group-xml-based-on-key