# Group XML based on key

Tags: xml, xslt

'Header(Max 1)
Details(Multiple)
PackingList(Max 1 & Optional)

InvoiceNumber is the key for Header, Details & Packing List.'
'My Input'

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ns0:SupplierInvoiceProcessing xmlns:ns0="test">
    <Invoice>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>1</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>Test4</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>2</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>c3</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>a1</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>1</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>2</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>5</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>d5</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>6</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>e6</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>b2</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    </Invoice>
    </ns0:SupplierInvoiceProcessing>
```

'I changed the xslt code to but still needs code modification to'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:ns0="test" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/*">
<SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification>
<xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice[Header]/(Header, Details, PackingList)" group-by="InvoiceNumber">
<AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
<ASN>
<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[self::Header], current-group()[self::Details], current-group()[self::PackingList]"/>
</ASN>
</AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

'I expect output to not include the ASN without Header.
Header, Details, Packing List grouped in ASN is mandatory. Need to strip any extra or no matching Packing Lists with Header.'

```
    <SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotificationxmlns:ns0="test">
    <AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
    <ASN>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>1</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>a4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>a1</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    </ASN>
    <ASN>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>2</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>d4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>4</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>Test4</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    </ASN>
    <ASN>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>2</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>b4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>2</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>b2</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    </ASN>
    <ASN>
    <Header>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <ETA>1</ETA>
    </Header>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c1</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c2</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c3</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <Details>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <OrderNumber>c4</OrderNumber>
    </Details>
    <PackingList>
    <ETA>20190221</ETA>
    <InvoiceNumber>3</InvoiceNumber>
    <FOBTotalNoOfCartons>c3</FOBTotalNoOfCartons>
    </PackingList>
    </ASN>
    </AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
    </SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition "Header, Details, Packing List grouped in ASN is mandatory" could be implemented in XSLT as

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
        <AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice/(Header, Details, PackingList)" group-by="InvoiceNumber, IN">
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[self::Header] and current-group()[self::Details] and current-group()[self::PackingList]">
                    <ASN>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[self::Header], current-group()[self::Details], current-group()[self::PackingList]"/>
                    </ASN>                        
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>                
        </AdvanceShipmentNotifications>
    </SupplierAdvanceShipmentNotification_XSL>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGC/3

I am currently not sure there is an easier way, you might want to run your XML (both the input as well as the wanted output) through some indentation/formatting before posting it so that we can more easily see the structure and the nesting.